# how not to display a popup in ionic app?

Tags: session, cookies, ionic-framework, popup, hide

In Ionic app, 
I have multiple screens and a popup shows for each specific screens.

Problem : Popups shows up every time.

Do you guys know the better way to hide popups after the user saw it once.

Garcias.

Answer (score 0):

A simple method I have used is a `$sessionStorage` variable that can be set to 'true' when the popup has been shown e.g.

```
$sessionStorage.seenPopup = false; // Or put this into your app.js on startup
    //On view enter  
       if(!$sessionStorage.seenPopup){
          //Show popup
          $sessionStorage.seenPopup = true;
        }
```

$sessionStorage is accesible across different views so you can 'turn off' a popup from elsewhere. Also you can use $localStorage to persist it.

Answer (score 0):

This answer is without the user of local storage. First and foremost - don't disable caching in the states you explained the problem in so that the controller isn't reinitialized every time. When the controller loads the first time it will show the popup but not for every other time you visit the page.

If you need to keep track of this even if the user kills the app on the phone then you need local storage, see @Tobin 's answer.